# Is it possible to create an ES6 Map with a ReactNative component as one of its nodes?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

My end result should be this :

```
const SECTIONS = [
  {
    title: 'First',
    content: <ReactComponent />,
  },
  {
    title: 'Second',
    content: <ReactComponent />,
  }
];
```

But I'm not sure if this is terrible. Here's my confused and ignorant attempt at this :

```
return [
  this.props.course.sections
    .map( (section, idx) => {title: section.title, content: <ReactComponent /> } );
]
```

The trouble it seems, is that this errs on the fact that it's not a proper hash so it doesn't recognize the `:`. Is this even possible in as shorthand as I'm trying to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `{}` with `()` to make it object literal not block.

```
return [
  this.props.course.sections
    .map( (section, idx) => ({title: section.title, content: <ReactComponent /> }) );
]
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh, thank you good sir. Thank you, now i shall have to wait 10 minute to grant you the correct answer title. Thanks so much

Comment: @Trip Glad I could help :)